# Why does a data structure with strict fields not get evaluated to WHNF immediatly?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I've been learning about strict vs lazy data structures, and have been playing around with the `:sprint` command in
ghci. My understanding of `:sprint` is it displays the evaluation status of selected variables. I've come across the following curiosity which I can't understand.

```
ghci> data Foo = Foo{i::Int,j::String}
ghci> data Bar = Bar{i:: !Int, j::String}
ghci> 
ghci> 
ghci> a = Foo (3+2) "abc"
ghci> b = Bar (3+2) "abc"
ghci> 
ghci> :sprint a
a = <Foo> _ _
ghci> :sprint b
b = _
```

My question is: why is `a` evaluated to WHNF by default, but `b` remains a thunk?

I was expecting the output of `b` to be `b = <Bar> 5 _`, which I can force by running `seq b ()`.

```
ghci> seq a ()
()
ghci> seq b ()
()
ghci> :sprint a
a = <Foo> _ _
ghci> :sprint b
b = <Bar> 5 _
```

Comment: because `b` itself is not strict. You force `i` in WHNF if `b` is evaluated to WHNF yes, but `b` is not evaluated at all.

Comment: Note that `b = Bar undefined "abc"` must not cause any exception until `b` is forced, so we can not evaluate it early. Rather, for the other case I'd have expected `a = _` instead of `a = <Foo> _ _` -- I guess GHC realized that `Foo` can be safely evaluated at definition time (?). Interesting.

Comment: @chi I think there's just nothing to evaluate. Calling a constructor just means allocating the constructor's memory block and storing the arguments of the call directly in its fields, and the constructor *itself* can't possibly cause an exception or fail to terminate. So there's no reason not to use the constructor to record the arguments of the call and store that directly in `a`, rather than creating a closure to record the arguments of the call and storing a thunk in `a`.

Comment: @Ben Sure, but `Foo undefined undefined` is distinct from `undefined :: Foo`. It's interesting to note that GHC optimizes `let a = Foo x y` so to not create a thunk since `Foo` will surely terminate. In the same spirit, it could optimize away many other thunks that are known to terminate (in a bounded number of steps). For instance, `a = Foo (3+2) "abc"` could create no thunks at all and immediately create `a = <Foo> 5 "abc"`, in principle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is because strict fields are just syntactic sugar, telling the compiler to automatically insert calls to `seq` in certain places.

So the strictness annotation on `Bar` means that `b = Bar (3+2) "abc"` is actually compiled as something like `b = let x = 3+2 in seq x (Bar x "abc")`.

After `a = Foo (3+2) "abc"`, `a` is a reference to an application of the constructor `Foo`; its fields contain thunks. Constructors are treated specially, so GHCi's `:sprint` can tell that the `a` refers to a constructor application and shows it as `a = <Foo> _ _`.

But after `b = Bar (3+2) "abc"`, `b` is a reference to an application of `seq`, not directly to an application of the constructor `Bar`. `seq` is just a function; it's special in terms of its implementation, but not in terms of being represented specially in memory the way constructors are. A reference to a (non-constructor) function application is just a thunk, so GHCi shows it as it would any other thunk: `b = _`.

*Forcing* the thunk referred to by `b` would force the `3 + 2` and then result in a reference to an application of the `Bar` constructor. But binding a variable doesn't automatically force the expression that is assigned to it.

Answer (score 3):

In GHC (or GHCi), the expression `Foo (3+2) "abc"` does not produce a thunk.  Instead, an optimization is performed to produce a `Foo` heap object directly, with fields pointing to thunks:

```
|------------------------|
| Foo                    |
|------------------------|
| pointer to thunk (3+2) |
|------------------------|
| pointer to thunk "abc" |
|------------------------|
```

The reason a thunk isn't produced is that it would be a waste of time.  The semantics are the same whether a thunk is created or not, and creating the object directly is no more expensive than creating the thunk, so it's a win whether or not the object is ever forced to WHNF.  (Okay, technically it might be *slightly* more expensive, but in realistic code where most objects are eventually used, it's an overall huge win to avoid these intermediate thunks.)

Now, you might think that the expression `Bar (3+2) "abc"` ought to behave the same way.  But here's the problem.  First, GHC can't create the heap object directly with the strict field forced to WHNF, as you are supposing:

```
|------------------------|
| Bar                    |
|------------------------|
| 5                      |
|------------------------|
| pointer to thunk "abc" |
|------------------------|
```

because that would change the semantics.

Specifically, the following code should not bottom:

```
test = let f = Foo undefined undefined
           b = Bar undefined undefined
       in ()

main = print test
```

Even though `b`'s first field is strict, `b` itself is not forced to WHNF, so its strict field should not be evaluated yet.  If GHC created the `Bar` object directly with the strict field in WHNF, it would need to create an object:

```
|----------------------------|
| Bar                        |
|----------------------------|
| BOTTOM                     |
|----------------------------|
| pointer to thunk undefined |
|----------------------------|
```

and it would encounter bottom during the object creation.  (In the general case, "bottom" might be an infinite loop, so it's not like GHC can build this object and put a special "bottom" value in the first field -- the evaluation itself will break in an unpredictable way before the object can be created.)  Now, you might *also* think that GHC could instead construct a partially evaluated object:

```
|----------------------------|
| Bar                        |
|----------------------------|
| pointer to thunk undefined |
|----------------------------|
| pointer to thunk undefined |
|----------------------------|
```

with a "note" that the next time this object actually gets forced to WHNF, the first field -- being strict -- will also be forced to WHNF.  Unfortunately, the GHC runtime can't support this.  The way GHC forces objects to WHNF is by inspecting the head of an object to see if it's a constructor or not.  If it's not a constructor, it needs to be further evaluated; if it's a constructor (like `Bar` here), it's already in WHNF.  So, this partially evaluated object would break GHC interals, as it would "appear" to be already forced to WHNF, even though its strict field has not been forced.

For this reason, GHC can't perform the same optimization it did for `Foo`, and the expression `Bar (3+2) "abc"` must be left as a thunk:

```
|----------------------------------|
| pointer to thunk Bar (3+2) "abc" |
|----------------------------------|
```

When it is forced to WHNF, that will trigger the first field to be forced to WHNF, and the resulting object will be placed on the heap, replacing this thunk:

```
|------------------------|
| Bar                    |
|------------------------|
| 5                      |
|------------------------|
| pointer to thunk "abc" |
|------------------------|
```